# Python sklearn onehotencoder

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to encode categorical data for the 4th feature of my vector which is in a numpy array. The categories are either '4' or '6'. I can change them into binary by using this:

```
 features_in_training_set = [[0 0 0 0 4], [0 0 0 0 4], [0 0 0 0 6],[0 0 0 0 4],[0 0 0 0 6]]

 features_in_training_set[:,4] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(features_in_training_set[:,4])
```

But, of course, I need to change this so that the classifier doesn't think that '4' is greater than '6'. However, when I run the following:

```
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[4], handle_unknown='ignore')

features_in_training_set = onehotencoder.fit_transform(features_in_training_set).toarray()
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

TypeError: Wrong type for parameter `n_values`. Expected 'auto', int or array of ints, got <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I've checked if I have any missing values or any strings and I don't. All features are integers.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are commas? `features_in_training_set = [[0 0 0 0 4], [0 0 0 0 4], [0 0 0 0 6],[0 0 0 0 4],[0 0 0 0 6]]`

Comment: @Konstantin it's a numpy array. Do numpy arrays have commas?

Comment: It will be numpy array after loading. Where is it converted to numpy array? When you write the code like this, its a list of lists which should have commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current `OneHotEncoder` in scikit-learn (> 0.20) can handle strings or other categorical features itself not requiring to use the `LabelEncoder` first to encode categories to numbers (or different numbers to unique sorted numbers as you did).

This error a bug in `OneHotEncoder` as its been evolving to handle the above case, and in the meanwhile should also support the older use-cases as your question. Adding `n_values='auto'` to the code will remove this error like this:

```
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[4], n_values='auto', 
                              handle_unknown='ignore')
```

If you remove the `handle_unknown` parameter from your code, then also this works, but that should not be done.

See this issue here:

- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/12881

Comment: Great, this gets rid of my error :) 
However, I noticed that the encoded columns are appended to the beginning of the feature vector, when I want to keep the order. Is this possible?

Comment: @user3755632 No. Its mentioned in the documentation that the encoded columns will be in beginning and other columns will be appended to right. If you want to take control, then [look at `FeatureUnion`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html).